# Camera feature not working in 4.4 version device android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-4.4-kitkat

In My button click I open camera like below:

```
private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 3;
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                            
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

My `OnActivityResult` Method code as below:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

         if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

            openGalleryImage(data);
            saveImage(uri_outputFileUri.getPath());
        } 
}
```

`openGalleryImage` Method:

```
private void openGalleryImage(Intent data) 
{
    Uri selectedimg = data.getData();
    Uri uriselectedimage=data.getData();
    mString=uriselectedimage.getPath();
    try 
    {
        mInputStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedimg);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] path = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedimg, path, null, null,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(path[0]);
    selectedimage_paths=c.getString(columnIndex);
    uri_outputFileUri= Uri.parse(selectedimage_paths);
    c.close();
}
```

`saveImage` Method:

```
private void saveImage(String mPath) 
{

    if (RentalApplicaiton.ISSDCARDPresent==true) {
        mediaDir= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/MyFolder");
        mediaDir.mkdir();
        submediaDir= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/MyFolder/TempFolder");
        submediaDir.mkdir();
    }
    else {
        mediaDir= new File(getCacheDir() ,"/MyFolder");
        mediaDir.mkdir();
        submediaDir= new File(getCacheDir() ,"/MyFolder/TempFolder");
        submediaDir.mkdir();
    }

    File myImage = new File(mediaDir, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png");
    File myImages = new File(submediaDir, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png");

    try 
    { 
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myImage);
        mbitmap_outputImage=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);    
        mbitmap_outputImage=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mbitmap_outputImage, 390, 310, true);
        mbitmap_outputImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); 
        out.flush();    
        out.close();
        getimagesfromSdcard();
        mGallery.setAdapter(mImageCustomAdapter);

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }  

    try 
    { 
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myImages);
        mbitmap_outputImage=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);    
        mbitmap_outputImage=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mbitmap_outputImage, 390, 310, true);
        mbitmap_outputImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); 
        out.flush();    
        out.close();
        getimagesfromSdcard();
        mGallery.setAdapter(mImageCustomAdapter);

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 

}
```

When I run this code, it is working fine on 4.0 to 4.3 devices, the issue only appears with 4.4 (Kitkat) devices. When I capture a photo on a 4.4 device, it directly force closes my application. Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Are the permissions set correctly?

Comment: @ stefan::Yes i give all permission perfectlly

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya.. Did you find the solution for this??